# In-order traversal of binary trees using fold in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to programme an in-order traversal of a binary tree in Haskell using a fold - which I've defined as:

```
foldB :: (x -> u -> u -> u) -> u -> BTree x -> u
foldB f a Nil = a
foldB f a (BNode x l r) = f x (foldB f a l) (foldB f a r)
```

I've defined an in-order traversal of a binary tree:

```
inorder :: Ord a => BTree a -> [a]
inorder Nil = []
inorder (BNode a x y) = inorder x ++ [a] ++ inorder y
```

But I can't seem to get them both to work together:

```
inorderFold :: Ord a => BTree a -> [a]
inorderFold = foldB inorder []
```

Comment: Are you trying to define `inorderFold` using `foldB`? If so, you just need `inorderFold = foldB (\c l r -> l ++ [c] ++ r) []`

Comment: thanks, code is working now